# Arcmap: Unable to detect empty value in row using Field Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser

I am using the following pre-logic Python code to try to catch Null, empty, or "0" string values in the "street" column and then return a "V" value if it  is one of those. While the code runs and works on some rows, it doesn't seem to be catching all empty cells. Am I missing a case? Or could it be that there are multiple spaces, and if so, how can I check for those?

Pre-Logic:

```
def check(Street):
  if Street is None or Street == "" or Street == "0" or Street == None or not Street or Street == " ":
    return "V" 
  else:
    return " "
```

Verfied =

```
check(!Street1!)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [strip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) method on a string will remove spaces and linebreaks so you can use it in your case to check for cases of multiple spaces.

```
def check(Street):
  if Street is None or Street.strip() == "" or Street == "0":
    return "V" 
  else:
    return " "
```